# Turkish Encoding problem while converting timestamp

Tags: php

My timestamps are stored in a row which is named "date". Then i convert this to readable date and i see encoding problem.

I used setlocale and strftime functions.

Example date stored in table: 2019-09-11 09:57:22

My readable date function is

```php
  static function readableDate($date)
  {
    setlocale(LC_TIME, 'tr_TR');
    return strftime('%e %B %Y', strtotime($date));
  }
```

Output is: "11 Eyl�l 2019". It should be "11 Eylül 2019"

Eylül means September. What should I do?

Comment: What is your page’s character encoding? UTF-8? Then you can try if your system knows a locale `tr_TR.UTF-8` maybe. Check the manual for setlocale, the user comments have a number of additional hints how to find a locale that works on your system. If none of those do the trick, you might need to encode the result of strftime to UTF-8 using utf8_encode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to use the `UTF` variant of this Turkish locale. It might be picking up `ISO` one.

what is the output of this:

```
locale -a | grep tr_TR
```

You may have to install `tr_TR.UTF-8` one and see if that one works.

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'tr_TR.UTF-8', 'tr_TR', 'Turkish');
```

Comment: setlocale(LC_TIME, 'tr_TR.UTF-8', 'tr_TR', 'Turkish');

it works, thank you Jay.